# ¿Por qué no usar el mismo nombre de una variable local a un campo?

Tags: java

He visto muchos vídeos de programadores que cambian las variables que el método requiere por no poner el mismo nombre que el de un campo.

```
public class Persona{

    private String nombre;

    public Persona(String nombre1){
        nombre = nombre1;
    }
}
```

Personalmente nunca lo he hecho y no sé por qué alguien querría hacerlo. Sin duda el código de abajo es mucho más elegante y legible...

```
public class Persona{

    private String nombre;

    public Persona(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

¿Hay alguna razón específica del porqué lo hacen de esta manera?

Comment: En lo personal no creo que haya alguna razón en específico, solo que es la forma de trabajar de algunas personas, sin embargo, por algo existe la palabra reservada `this` y en concreto uno de sus principales usos es para hacer referencia al objeto actual, con esto, a mi parecer, es tener bien identificado o mapeadas las variables con las que se trabaja en ese contexto. Aquí http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html la documentación oficial de Java

Comment: @Flxtr es exactamente lo que pensé, pero recuerdo que en algunos videos especificamente decían que **no** se debería poner el mismo nombre, por eso la duda, lo que es muy raro por qué el programador que lo dijo es digno de admirar, una leyenda , pero bueno al parecer se equivocaba, gracias por compartir tu opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Sí lo hay. La palabra clave `this` como autoreferencia provee desambigüedad entre variable y campo sin perder la información que se trata de la misma referencia.

```
private String nombre;
private String apellido;

public MiClase(String nombre){
    // this is just a four letter word - Bob Dylan
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

No deja espacio para malentendidos. Sin embargo lo siguiente sería confuso y contraproducente, aunque funcionaría:

```
public void setApellido(String nombre){
    // mala practica
    apellido = nombre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El ejemplo de Stefan Nolde es claro, pero opino que hay ocasiones en que sí es correcto utilizar diferentes nombres de variables de cara a hacer un código más legible. La clave está en dar valor semántico a esos nombres. 
Por ejemplo:

```
private String numeroCuenta;

public void modificarCuentaCorriente(String nuevoNumeroCuenta){

    if (!numeroCuenta.equals(nuevoNumeroCuenta)){
        //más operaciones de validación de nuevoNumeroCuenta

        numeroCuenta = nuevoNumeroCuenta;
    }

}
```

Me parece un código más claro que usar el this para diferenciar dos variables con mismo nombre

Answer (score 0):

Eso sólo depende de quien haga el código,  quizá la razón sea por que así lo aprendieron y así se han acostumbrado.
Pero Concuerdo contigo en que usando el **this** se ve mejor el código.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible usando la palabra reservada this, no habrá ningún problema en tiempo de compilación o ejecución, pero hace se confuso cuando tienes 2 variables (o en este caso una variable y una propiedad) con el mismo nombre a la hora hacerles referencia en el fuente. Lo ideal sería colocarles nombres caracteristicos, eje;

public class Persona {

```
    private String nombre;

    public Persona(String nuevoNombre){
        nombre = nuevoNombre;
    }
}
```

Usar un nombre mas descriptivo puede mejorar la lectura del código y otros programadores te lo agradecerán.